# How to Use Ready Made Custom Forms in Django

Tags: python, django

So, I am in the process of learning Django. And creating a simple RSS app. I need a login/registration form. I found this pretty looking form on Codepen and I want to use it.

[Slide Login and Signup Form](https://codepen.io/isahayankit/pen/mNEKXz)

It uses a lot of DIVs with classes and is confusing me on how to write the form template for this.

Also, would be possible to use the same URL for registration as well as login.

Suppose this `myapp/login`

Both login and registration will use POST requests and what would be the best way to differentiate them? to identify whether an event is user registration or login.

Need help for this, thanks. I don't really need code... if anyone can just explain this that'd be great.

Comment: You can use PUT instead of POST for one of the tasks (better for registration for semantic reasons) to reuse the URL. You can add a differentiating field to POST body (e.g. `goal=authentication` vs `goal=registration`). But why do you need this?

Comment: @SUTerliakov it's just I liked this form.